# Search a vector in a specific element of a nested list in R

Tags: r, list

To explain what I want to do exactly, I will use the following example:

```
a = list(x = 5, y = c(11, 12, 13))
b = list(x = 4.7, y = c(112, 5, 2))
c = list(x = 77, y = c(5, 1, 1))
d = list(x = 5, y = c(22, 11, 43))
test_list = list(a, b, c, d)
```

I have a nested list: `test_list`. I would like to search vector `5` only in element **`x`** in the tested_list, and return the indices of the list, e.g., here as c(1,4).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with `lapply` like here:

```
a = list(x = 5, y = c(11, 12, 13))
b = list(x = 4.7, y = c(112, 5, 2))
c = list(x = 77, y = c(5, 1, 1))
d = list(x = 5, y = c(22, 11, 43))
test_list = list(a, b, c, d)

which(unlist(lapply(test_list, function(x) {

    x$x == 5

})))
```

First you choose `x` then for `5` then `unlist` and then check which are `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 which(vapply(test_list, function(x) x[["x"]] == 5, logical(1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, using `purrr`:

```
which(map_lgl(test_list, ~ pluck(., "x") == 5))

[1] 1 4
```

Answer (score 1):

As 'x' is of `length` 1 in each `list` element, it may be better to do the comparison at once after extracting the element

```
which(sapply(test_list, `[[`, 'x')==5)
#[1] 1 4
```